# How to read Unicode symbols from a text file in C++

Tags: c++, unicode

I can't read Unicode symbols from my text file (UTF8) using ifstream() but there is something strange. Could you help me with methods to use and what parameters to use in the `ifstream` function?

Comment: At least post some of the content of the text file.

Comment: Text - with words in Russian

Comment: Please post your code and example input and output. Otherwise it will be difficult to help you

Answer (score 0):

you can use std namespace string and ifstream for that.

```
ifstream in("1.txt");
string s;
while(getline(in,s)
{
  for(int i = 0; i<s.length; i++){
     cout << s[i] ;
  }

}
in.close();
```

Comment: you can traverse through string anytime